# Restoring access to telegram bots after deleting the owner's account

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram deleted my account by timing (after half a year without activity), this account had several combat bots. After deleting the account, the bots were not deleted, but now I don’t understand how I can restore access to them. I tried to re-register on a new account. The list of bots is empty.

I wrote to Telegram support, 2 weeks have passed and there is no response from them. I was looking for a similar situation on the Internet but did not find a similar one. Out of despair, I am writing here.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on Stack Overflow. This site is about Q/A for programming related topics.

Comment: When a telegram account gets deleted, the attached bots are also deleted.
I dont think there existence is possible.

Comment: About 3 weeks ago, the account was deleted, but the bots are still working. I wouldn't ask a question if the bots also left)

Comment: did telegram support reply your question after all this time? I actually now in similar situation...  telegram support not reply to my question about 1 week now

Comment: I still haven't gotten any feedback on this telegram issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only way to solve this is to ask support.

Because if you'll create bot with the same name again - you'll lose your users. As you would normally delete and create bot.

So, ping them in all available channels, hope and wait.

Comment: I think you are right. But contacting Telegram turned out to be more difficult than I expected.

Comment: The situation at the moment: telegram did not answer any of the communication channels. The bots are still working, but it was not possible to get access to them.